# extract text in between HTML td tags

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, tags

I have a `<td>` and want to extract the text from it, that is I need just the text **Tom Cruz, Homer Simpson, Bill Clinton** which is inside each `<td>` tag using one python regular expression.

```
<td class="clic-cul manga" template=".woxColumnyd" maz="/ajax/blac-woxm/xom-line/expanded/2002-2012/11-05-2022/01/fam.json">Tom Cruz</td>

<td class="clic-cul manga" template=".woxColumnx" mac="/ajax/blac-woxm/xom-line/expanded/2002-2012/11-05-2022/01/fam.json">Home Simpson</td>

<td class="clic-cul manga" template=".woxColumnz" max="/ajax/blac-woxm/xom-line/expanded/2002-2012/11-05-2022/01/fam.json">Bill Clinton</td>
```

Any ideas?

**Updates 1. If HTML Parser is the standard way, how should I go about it?**

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: The standard way is to use a html parser and not a regex

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a regex-only solution but I would urge you to consider other safer, faster and simpler approaches using one of the lxml-based libraries like html5lib or BeautifulSoup, that can parse invalid HTML and provide access to lxml trees.

With BeautifulSoup:

```py
html = """
<td class="clic-cul manga" template=".woxColumnyd" maz="/ajax/blac-woxm/xom-line/expanded/2002-2012/11-05-2022/01/fam.json">Tom Cruz</td>
<td class="clic-cul manga" template=".woxColumnx" mac="/ajax/blac-woxm/xom-line/expanded/2002-2012/11-05-2022/01/fam.json">Home Simpson</td>
<td class="clic-cul manga" template=".woxColumnz" max="/ajax/blac-woxm/xom-line/expanded/2002-2012/11-05-2022/01/fam.json">Bill Clinton</td>
"""

import bs4
doc = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print([el.text for el in doc.find_all('td')])
```

The output is then

```
['Tom Cruz', 'Home Simpson', 'Bill Clinton']
```

Answer (score 0):

**IF you are looking for a one liner regex- 
`>\u+(\s\u+)?</`**

IF NOT
LET SAY you have that html stored in a file named `dat.txt`.
I don't know about python but I know ruby.
Maybe you could make out something.

```
xfile3=File.open("dat.txt","r")     #html stored in dat.txt
i=-2                                #Logic here. For iterating i exactly to the position of names in the array
ch= xfile3.read
arr=ch.split(/[<,>]/)               #for splitting ch into arr whenever < or > is encountered
while i<=100                        # replace 100 to some no as it suits
    i=i+4           
    puts arr[i]                     
end
```

Working proof
[image: PROOF]